# Tilted background with rounded corners

Tags: css, svg, background, responsive, clip-path

I'm trying to create a background for my divs which is like a rectangle (with rounded corners) but with the right corner lower than the left one. **The height difference** between those two corners **must remain the same** independently of the total height of the background.

Something like that :

[image]

I don't know which solution is the best : a full svg, or working only with clip-path in my css.

I tried to create manually an svg but the result seems not enough precise.

```html
  <svg width="500" height="200">
    <defs>
      <mask id="roundCorner">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>

        //left corner
        <rect width="50" height="50" fill="black"/>
        <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="white"/>
        
        //right corner
        <rect x='450' y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="black"/>
        <circle r="50" cx="450" cy="76" fill="white"/>

        //line
        <path d="M50 0 L500 30 L500 0 Z" fill='black'  />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="lime" mask="url(#roundCorner)"/>
  </svg>
```

So how can I achieve a clean background like this in an efficient way ?

Answer (score 0):

First one you need to take the shape in svg format like this.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 220">
<path fill="#4F92C2" d="M449.8,220H50c-27.6,0-50-22.4-50-50V51.5C0,23.1,23.1,0,51.5,0l403.2,44.1c25.8,2.8,45.3,24.6,45.3,50.5v75.2  C500,197.5,477.5,220,449.8,220z"/>
</svg>
```

Next, you need a online svg to css clip path converter [here](https://www.plantcss.com/). In that converter you have coordinate points it help us to you can set which portions are always same shape when extend the element width or height.

It means from your question the right corner lower than the left one if height is increase, so top right coordinates points **gold color** marked in below screen shot,

- set x-axis values to "**right**" in case if width increase it can't stretch because that portion shape always need to right side.
- set y-axis values to "**top**" in case if height increase it can't stretch, that portion shape always need to top side.

[image]

In above image remaining coordinate values following as,

**Black Marked - Bottom Right**

- x-axis to "right".
- y-axis to "bottom" because always need in bottom area.

**Indigo Marked - Bottom Left**

- x-axis to "left" because it is already in left side.  So, no need to change values.
- y-axis to "bottom".

**Green Marked - Top Left**

- x-axis to "left".
- y-axis to "top". So, no need change both values.

Finally you get the code like below, after you change the all coordinates values what if need and click the Get Code button.

```css
.tilted_background_resize
{
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
}
.tilted_background 
{   
  
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 50.2px) calc(100% - 0px), 50px calc(100% - 0px), 50px calc(100% - 0px), 41.8932px calc(100% - 0.65479999999999px), 34.2016px calc(100% - 2.5503999999999px), 27.0284px calc(100% - 5.5836px), 20.4768px calc(100% - 9.6512px), 14.65px calc(100% - 14.65px), 9.6512px calc(100% - 20.4768px), 5.5836px calc(100% - 27.0284px), 2.5504px calc(100% - 34.2016px), 0.6548px calc(100% - 41.8932px), 8.2830395048206E-31px calc(100% - 50px), 0px 51.5px, 0px 51.5px, 0.6752px 43.1568px, 2.6296px 35.2384px, 5.7564px 27.8516px, 9.9488px 21.1032px, 15.1px 15.1px, 21.1032px 9.9488px, 27.8516px 5.7564px, 35.2384px 2.6296px, 43.1568px 0.6752px, 51.5px 8.5418844893463E-31px, calc(100% - 45.3px) 44.1px, calc(100% - 45.3px) 44.1px, calc(100% - 37.7622px) 45.4951px, calc(100% - 30.6816px) 47.9408px, calc(100% - 24.1374px) 51.3477px, calc(100% - 18.2088px) 55.6264px, calc(100% - 12.975px) 60.6875px, calc(100% - 8.5152px) 66.4416px, calc(100% - 4.9086px) 72.7993px, calc(100% - 2.2344px) 79.6712px, calc(100% - 0.5718px) 86.9679px, calc(100% - 0px) 94.6px, calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 50.2px), calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 50.2px), calc(100% - 0.65769999999998px) calc(100% - 42.0633px), calc(100% - 2.5615999999998px) calc(100% - 34.3424px), calc(100% - 5.6079px) calc(100% - 27.1411px), calc(100% - 9.6928px) calc(100% - 20.5632px), calc(100% - 14.7125px) calc(100% - 14.7125px), calc(100% - 20.5632px) calc(100% - 9.6928px), calc(100% - 27.1411px) calc(100% - 5.6079px), calc(100% - 34.3424px) calc(100% - 2.5616px), calc(100% - 42.0633px) calc(100% - 0.65770000000001px), calc(100% - 50.2px) calc(100% - 0px)); 
  background-color: #4F92C2;
}
```

```html
<div class="tilted_background_resize">
  <div class="tilted_background"></div>
</div>
```